# save json jq output as seperate variables or as an array

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq, i3

I am currently working with i3 and would like to parse the visible workspaces with `i3-msg -t get_workspaces`, to "save the workspace" and return to them when my pomodoro break is over, problem is I've never worked with json in bash before (aside from a couple quick examples maybe an hour ago).
basically I am trying to return the name value of the visible workspaces.

```json
[
  {
    "id": 94475011596992,
    "num": 6,
    "name": "6:NoteTaking",
    "visible": false,
    "focused": false,
    "rect": {
      "x": 40,
      "y": 65,
      "width": 1840,
      "height": 975
    },
    "output": "DisplayPort-2",
    "urgent": false
  },
  {
    "id": 94475011603104,
    "num": 7,
    "name": "7:Entertainment",
    "visible": false,
    "focused": false,
    "rect": {
      "x": 40,
      "y": 65,
      "width": 1840,
      "height": 975
    },
    "output": "DisplayPort-2",
    "urgent": false
  },
  {
    "id": 94475011612464,
    "num": 9,
    "name": "9",
    "visible": true,
    "focused": true,
    "rect": {
      "x": 40,
      "y": 65,
      "width": 1840,
      "height": 975
    },
    "output": "DisplayPort-2",
    "urgent": false
  },
  {
    "id": 94475011631328,
    "num": 1,
    "name": "1:Browsing",
    "visible": true,
    "focused": false,
    "rect": {
      "x": 40,
      "y": 1145,
      "width": 1840,
      "height": 975
    },
    "output": "DisplayPort-1",
    "urgent": false
  },
  {
    "id": 94475011637712,
    "num": 2,
    "name": "2:Messaging",
    "visible": false,
    "focused": false,
    "rect": {
      "x": 40,
      "y": 1145,
      "width": 1840,
      "height": 975
    },
    "output": "DisplayPort-1",
    "urgent": false
  },
  {
    "id": 94475011644096,
    "num": 3,
    "name": "3",
    "visible": false,
    "focused": false,
    "rect": {
      "x": 40,
      "y": 1145,
      "width": 1840,
      "height": 975
    },
    "output": "DisplayPort-1",
    "urgent": false
  }
]
```

Currently I have this line doing most of the heavy lifting,

```bash
  local currentWorkspaces=$(i3-msg -t get_workspaces | jq -r 'map(select(.visible == true)).name')
```

it's returning the right values (granted they are in quotes.)

```json
[
  "9",
  "1:Browsing"
]
```

I've been trying to call them with a simple array (never worked with arrays either so might be messing stuff up)
`i3-msg workspace "$currentWorkspaces[@]"`

currently I have no idea how to move forward, and any help would be appreciated (-r the option I thought would return the values without quotes isn't doing so)

Comment: The `jq` expression is still an array so the `-r` doesn't do anything. You need to peel off the array and have `jq` return just the values, concatenated. Try adding `| "\(.[0]) \(.[1])"` to the end (not sure of the precise syntax; not in a place where I can test; and this generalizes poorly to a list of arbitrary length).

Comment: I was unable to repro with your test data, but https://jqplay.org/s/1BuqQ51k0oh seems to do what you are asking.

Comment: If indeed your current filter works, try adding `| @sh` or `| @tsv` at the end.

Comment: @Jameson What (exactly) is the output you expect from jq? If it is just the (unquoted) names, separated by newlines, then tripleee's suggestion is your answer (which can further be simplified/contracted to `jq -r '.[]  | select(.visible).name'`). The `-r` flag is necessary if you want to convert JSON string results (which is what the final `.name` produces) into raw (not JSON-encoded) strings. Your previous attempt (using `map`) produced an array, so `-r` had no effect.

Comment: I want to be able to have both the outputs saved in a way I can call them using `i3-msg workspace output1` and `i3-msg workspace output2' or the ideal solution would be to have it stored in a array, that way it's not dependent on me having 2 workspaces exclusively, as for the format i would like no quotation marks just the variable example 7:Entertainment or 1:Browsing

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, just woke up and haven't had time to test suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the values in .name have no spaces or certain other characters,
you would be able to get away with something along the lines of the following:

```
X=($(i3-msg -t get_workspaces | jq -r '.[] | select(.visible == true).name' ))

for var in "${X[@]}"
do
  echo "$var"
done
```

Output:

```
9
1:Browsing
```

More robustly, if your shell has `readarray`:

```
readarray -t X < <(... | jq -r '.[] | select(.visible == true).name ')
```

Otherwise, you could use the idiom:

```
vars=(); while IFS= read -r line; do vars+=("$line"); done < .....
```

Comment: Using `read -d ''` in combination with `jq --raw-output0` would be another way.

Comment: the for loop answer was what worked for me(had to run a script in the background with $), thanks soo much everyone for all your help, I have a lot of reading material because of this.

Comment: I made a change to the first snippet from `for var in "${X[@]}"` to `for var in ${X}` because the X variable is not an array, it is a string with a newline in it. With the original for loop, there's only 1 iteration: when a scalar variable is expanded with array syntax, you get the scalar value. That is still the wrong approach: use `readarray` as shown.

Comment: @glennjackman : `echo $BASH_VERSION;X=(a b);declare -p X` # yields: 5.1.16(1)-release 
declare -a X=([0]="a" [1]="b")

Comment: Except you're not doing `declare -a X=(...)` to create an array, you're doing `declare -a X=$(...)` -- a command substitition results in a scalar value, the text captured. `declare -a X=$(echo foo; echo bar); declare -p X` => `declare -a X=([0]=$'foo\nbar')`

Comment: @glennjackman - Indeed. I added the outer parens. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

> the ideal solution would be to have it stored in a array

Assuming you mean a bash array, you can use `declare` to declare it, and use jq's `@sh` to properly escape the contents.

For an indexed array, use `declare -a`:

```bash
$ declare -a cw="($(i3-msg … | jq -r '.[]  | select(.visible).name | @sh'))"

$ declare -p cw  # print for testing
declare -a cw=([0]="9" [1]="1:Browsing")
```

For an associative array, use `declare -A`, and output each keys before its value:

```bash
$ declare -A cw="($(i3-msg … | jq -r '.[]  | select(.visible) | .output, .name | @sh'))"

$ declare -p cw  # print for testing
declare -A cw=([DisplayPort-2]="9" [DisplayPort-1]="1:Browsing" )
```